# Getting old 40MB hard drive usable in Windows with USB adapter

Tags: hard-drive, pata, pio

I have some old hard drives (~40MB) and a couple different USB-to-IDE adapters.  When I fire up these old drives, I'm able to see the drive model name in various disk utilities under Windows 7.  Fortunately, my USB adapters support PIO Mode 0!  The device is detected, but the storage parameters are not.  I'm not able to read partitions or anything.  I'm assuming this is because these drives from the days when you had to enter a drive type number somewhere.

Is there any sort of way to do this under Windows 7?  Any sort of utility I can use?

Comment: Are you sure the partition tables are still intact?

Comment: I hope you don't need them because of a lack of storage. :-)

Comment: @TimG I'm not sure of anything but I have 15 drives of similar sizes here with the identical problem, so I'd imagine at least some of them work still.

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 It's for my new RAOD setup.  :-)  Redundant Array of Old Disks.  I thought about making a car adapter so I can stick a drive in like I do my 8-tracks... then I can play my MIDI files in the car.

Comment: _ but the storage parameters are not_ Oooh, pre-plug-n-play/LBA where you had to know Heads-Tracks-Sectors and enter the count into the Bios or the drive was unreadable... Time to do some serious specification mining if you can find it.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Fortunately the heads and cylinders and what not are written on top of most of the drives.  I just need to figure out where to put that stuff in Windows.

Comment: You put it in BIOS if you still have a BIOS that has the ability. Might have to find an old computer.

Comment: @FiascoLabs Unfortunately I have no such old computer anymore and need to use my USB adapter if it's possible.  It seems like it should be technically possible as communication is working... drive ID is sent and what not.

Comment: Maybe look at stuff like SpinRite and its alternatives:  http://alternativeto.net/software/spinrite/